# SQL structure for storing and retrieving multiples/different values in/from the single column?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database-design

Can anyone please tell/suggest me how can i store and retrieve comments multiple/different values in/from the single column?

Scenario: Some user makes a post and rest of the users are posting comments on it.

Here i have a table names "posts" in MySQL database with the following columns "id","posted_by","post" and "comments"

Now i'm stuck in the comments part where i'm trying to store the comments made by different people in the single column and retrieving and displaying comments them right below the post.

I thought of using ALTER and create new columns for different comments but i don't think thats a good idea thats why i'm posting this question.

Thank You

Comment: here's article you may want to read, http://www.datanamic.com/support/lt-dez005-introduction-db-modeling.html, focus on **Identifying Relationships** section

Comment: Thanks LiuYan for the links :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create another table

```
COMMENT

id comment commenter post datetime
```

and remove `comments` from POST table, so now POST can have many COMMENT

Comment: Thanks for the response.Is it a good idea to create separate table to store comments? i mean what if there are 1000 posts? Than i'll have 1000 tables for comments?!

Comment: if there are 1000 posts then there would be 1000 entried (rows) in POST table in a single table